# PHP mysqli table query gives multiple results that i want to query against another table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been working on a social network, i have a fanpages table that a user can create a profile for their favorite band or celebrity and another table called friends where they can subscribe to the fanpages. i then want the requests to appear in notifications for the fanpage admin to except.
after the first sql query it returns fanpages with multiple values but if i echo the next $sql query it shows that its only selecting one result to query instead of all of them.

so basically i need to query fanpages table for all fanpages created_by the user logged on ($log_username), then i need to take those fanpages and query the friends table to find out if anyone has requested to subscribe to the users fan pages??

thanks for your help Michael

```
    <?php
$fanpage_requests = '';

$fansql = "SELECT created_by, fanpage_name FROM `fanpages`  WHERE created_by = '$log_username' ";
$fanquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $fansql);
$fannumrows = mysqli_num_rows($fanquery);

if($fannumrows < 1){
    $fanpage_requests = 'No friend requests';
} else {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fanquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $fanpage_name = $row["fanpage_name"];
        $created_by = $row["created_by"];

        $fansubSql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='$fanpage_name' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASC";
        $fansubQuery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $fansubSql);
        $fansubNumrows = mysqli_num_rows($fansubQuery);
        //print_r ($fansubNumrows);     
        if($fansubNumrows < 1){
            $fanpage_requests = "blah blah"; 
        }
        print_r ($fansubNumrows);
        while ($fansubRow = mysqli_fetch_array($fansubQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $fansubreqID = $fansubRow["id"];
            $fansubuser1 = $fansubRow["user1"];
            $fansubdatemade = $fansubRow["datemade"];
            $fansubdatemade = strftime("%B %d", strtotime($fansubdatemade));

            $fansubthumbquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username='$fansubuser1' LIMIT 1");
            $fansubthumbrow = mysqli_fetch_row($fansubthumbquery);
            $fansubuser1avatar = $fansubthumbrow[0];
            $fansubuser1pic = '<img src="user/'.$fansubuser1.'/'.$fansubuser1avatar.'" alt="'.$fansubuser1.'" class="user_pic">';

            if($fansubuser1avatar == NULL){
                $fansubuser1pic = '<img src="images/avatardefault.jpg" alt="'.$fansubuser1.'" class="user_pic">';
            }

            $fanpage_requests .= '<div id="friendreq_'.$fansubreqID.'" class="friendrequests">';
            $fanpage_requests .= '<a href="user.php?u='.$fansubuser1.'">'.$fansubuser1pic.'</a>';
            $fanpage_requests .= '<div class="user_info" id="user_info_'.$fansubreqID.'">'.$fansubdatemade.' <a href="user.php?u='.$fansubuser1.'">'.$fansubuser1.'</a> requests friendship<br /><br />';
            $fanpage_requests .= '<button onclick="fanReqHandler(\'accept\',\''.$fansubreqID.'\',\''.$fansubuser1.'\',\'user_info_'.$fansubreqID.'\')">accept</button> or ';
            $fanpage_requests .= '<button onclick="fanReqHandler(\'reject\',\''.$fansubreqID.'\',\''.$fansubuser1.'\',\'user_info_'.$fansubreqID.'\')">reject</button>';
            $fanpage_requests .= '</div>';
            $fanpage_requests .= '</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

print_r output is now 001110 and i get blah blah

Comment: your first loop sets `$fanpage_name` but you close it before you do anything else, so all other actions happen outside that loop and just use the last value for `$fanpage_name`. You need to close your loop later.

Comment: I thought that was the case as well but i move the end } to the end of the code and i get just 1 result still (it is a different result and its not a result that has a subscribe request) basically the first query returns (fan1, fan2, fan3, fan4) all the pages created by the logged on user and it returned fan4 which was created by and had subscription request but moving } to the end of code gives me fan1 yes created by logged on user but doesn't have subscribe request?

Comment: Michael, can you attach the output you get please?

Comment: I'm getting, SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='fan4' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASC from the $fanpage_requests = "$friendsSql"; line of code

Comment: So are you getting just this one line output? If so, then the first query (from `fanpages`) is returning only 1 line, so I would say only `fanpage_name` 'fan4' is fulfilling the first query conditions. How many fanpages have been created by `$log_username`?

Comment: nope it should return 2 both fan3 and fan4 have requests waiting so something isn't right

Comment: log_username has about 6 fanpages that were created by that user only 2 have requests to subscribe to them

Comment: Hi Michael - can you edit your question and post the results for `SELECT created_by, fanpage_name FROM fanpages WHERE created_by = '$log_username'` into a code section at the end please?

Comment: edit my question? do you mean start a new question with the results of that query in it?

Comment: no, just click the `edit` link under your question text and paste the results at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so having established that you need to close your loop later, the reason it does not work correctly is because now you are using the same variables in the different loops, so values are being overwritten (e.g. `$query`).

You need to differentiate your loops clearly, in terms of all variables that need to be different:

```
<?php
    $friend_requests = '';

    $sql = "SELECT created_by, fanpage_name FROM `fanpages`  WHERE created_by = '$log_username' ";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows < 1){
        $friend_requests = 'No friend requests';
    } else {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $fanpage_name = $row["fanpage_name"];
            $created_by = $row["created_by"];

            $friendsSql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='$fanpage_name' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASC";
            $friendsQuery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $friendsSql);
            $friendsNumrows = mysqli_num_rows($friendsQuery);
            $fanpage_requests = "$friendsSql";

            if($friendsNumrows < 1){
                $fanpage_requests = "$fanpage_name"; **//this shows that only 1 query is being queried in this second sql statement**
            }

            while ($friendsRow = mysqli_fetch_array($friendsQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $reqID = $friendsRow["id"];
                $user1 = $friendsRow["user1"];
                $datemade = $friendsRow["datemade"];
                $datemade = strftime("%B %d", strtotime($datemade));

                $thumbquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username='$user1' LIMIT 1");
                $thumbrow = mysqli_fetch_row($thumbquery);
                $user1avatar = $thumbrow[0];
                $user1pic = '<img src="user/'.$user1.'/'.$user1avatar.'" alt="'.$user1.'" class="user_pic">';

                if($user1avatar == NULL){
                    $user1pic = '<img src="images/avatardefault.jpg" alt="'.$user1.'" class="user_pic">';
                }

                $fanpage_requests .= '<div id="friendreq_'.$reqID.'" class="friendrequests">';
                $fanpage_requests .= '<a href="user.php?u='.$user1.'">'.$user1pic.'</a>';
                $fanpage_requests .= '<div class="user_info" id="user_info_'.$reqID.'">'.$datemade.' <a href="user.php?u='.$user1.'">'.$user1.'</a> requests friendship<br /><br />';
                $fanpage_requests .= '<button onclick="fanReqHandler(\'accept\',\''.$reqID.'\',\''.$user1.'\',\'user_info_'.$reqID.'\')">accept</button> or ';
                $fanpage_requests .= '<button onclick="fanReqHandler(\'reject\',\''.$reqID.'\',\''.$user1.'\',\'user_info_'.$reqID.'\')">reject</button>';
                $fanpage_requests .= '</div>';
                $fanpage_requests .= '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: ok i tried your code out and i'm still getting the same result it uses the last result fan4 to search the records in friends table instead of looping and querying fan1, fan2, fan3 and fan4 to see if they have requested to subscribe

Comment: @MichaelFrost - please execute the query `SELECT created_by, fanpage_name FROM fanpages WHERE created_by = 'insert log_username here'`, copy the resulting output, then edit **your** question and paste the output you copied at the end of **your** question.

Comment: ok looking at what is returned from the first query it is only returning fan4 but checking the database i have 2 records waiting for the logged on user to except

Comment: @MichaelFrost - Surely if you select records for the "logged on user", you are executing the same query, either via PHP or via whatever query tool you use. How are you checking the database? What query are you running to get 2 records? I believe the problem now lies in your data, not in the code.

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin to check the data in the tables

Comment: @MichaelFrost - you need to check your data carefully and adjust the query in the page if necessary. I can only help you so far, and I believe the way the code handles the data **is** correct. if you want further help you will need to post examples of your raw data and what you get from running the queries.

Comment: ok if i echo $fansql i get :SELECT created_by, fanpage_name FROM fanpages WHERE created_by = 'Jeff' (jeff being the user logged in) so its solving $log_username correctly

Comment: echo $fannumrows echos the number 6 which is correct there are 6 fanpages created by jeff

Comment: print_r $row outputs this:Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Russell Howard ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Audi cars ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Star Wars ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => The Matrix ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Green Day ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Guns N Roses )

Comment: print_r $fansubSql outputs: SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Russell Howard' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Audi cars' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Star Wars' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='The Matrix' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Green Day' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Guns N Roses' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASC

Comment: its at this point it fails it reaches the if($fansubNumrows < 1){ $fanpage_requests = "blah blah"; } and it outputs blah blah so its checking the records but suggesting that there are no requests waiting, but if you look in phpmyadmin 3 records have accepted = 0 created by jeff

Comment: if i do print_r ($fansubNumrows) it out puts this: Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => Ben [2] => Star Wars [3] => 2013-03-13 14:10:49 [4] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 33 [1] => Jeff [2] => The Matrix [3] => 2013-03-13 14:24:55 [4] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 32 [1] => Ben [2] => Green Day [3] => 2013-03-13 14:11:03 [4] => 0 ) which is correct 3 records created by jeff with 0 in accepted [4]

Comment: @MichaelFrost - ok, there's a bug. In my code `$friendsNumrows = mysqli_fetch_row($friendsQuery);` should be `$friendsNumrows = mysqli_num_rows($friendsQuery);` I have amended it, so please change your code accordingly. Also, it's no use trying to edit **my** answer - you need to edit **your** question if you want to show the code you are now using.

Comment: i'm still getting the message blah blah so its still suggesting that no records are waiting even though the mysqli query says there are 3 waiting?

Comment: if i comment out the if statement with blah blah it then shows 3 requests but doesn't display what pages they are for only the users trying to request subscription and if i try to accept it doesnt update the records.

Comment: @MichaelFrost - can you please **edit your question** (**not** my answer - that won't work) and add the code you are now using to the end of your question text.

Comment: if i insert a print_r($fansubNumrows) after the if statement with blah blah after the update you asked me to do i get 001110

Comment: sorry Raad thought i had updated my question i have done it now